# How to add PHP file to Blazor?

Tags: php, blazor, email-client

I have seen it can be done with PeachPie, but it requires you to host a server and I do not want a server with my blazor app. So is there any way to do it without a server?

What I am trying to do is send email using a Contact form, but all c# methods I have seen requires a server, but I have seen PHP ways of sending emails that doesn't require a server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I have seen PHP ways of sending emails that doesn't require a server`...can you explain / give us a link? PHP runs on a server, always. It's not clear precisely what you mean.

Comment: You need a server to send email.  You can't just send mail from any old computer masquerading as an SMTP relay.  Most systems will immediately deal with such mail as spam.  Why mix PHP and Blazor? Sounds like a dog's breakfast to me!

Comment: Blazor Server still runs on a server. Blazor WebAssembly is just like any other SPA - it can only do what the browser allows, and the browser *does not* allow SMTP, only HTTP calls. If you want to send an email you'll have to use your own server or an email service with an HTTP API

Comment: `How to add PHP file to Blazor?` is unclear. That's like asking `how to add PHP to Node` or `hot to add PHP to React`. What makes sense is calling a service written in PHP from React, Node or Blazor